# how to get list of top influencer in instagram with node js or react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, instagram, instagram-api, mern

how to get list of top influencer in Instagram with Node js or react js ?
is it possible to get their email?

and is it possible to do the same think with the other social media platforme

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

social media platforms would be allowed to share peoples personal emails.

how ever to get a list of the top with node js. I recommend you looking over the instagram
API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api